# How is returning an object by reference possible?

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management

I was reading an OpenCV tutorial and it said the following about OpenCV's image holder class (cv::Mat):

```
The cv::Mat class implements reference counting and shallow copy such that when an image 
is assigned to another one, the image data (that is the pixels) is not copied, and both images 
will point to the same memory block. This also applies to images passed by value or returned 
by value. A reference count is kept such that the memory will be released only when all of the 
references to the image will be destructed.
```

I'm specficially interested in the part that says `This also applies to images passed by value or returned.` How is it possible to point to the same memory block when it is passed by value? I feel like this is something to do with overloading the `=` operator. But it says even if an image is returned, it only returns an image that points to the same memory block and doesn't create a new one. I don't understand how they implemented this.

But here's what I DO understand:

Given that pass by value and returning an image make the new image share the same memory block, it makes sense to implement reference counting.

But could you explain how the memory block is shared, even when an object is returned or passed by value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively easy: In the class' constructor, you allocate memory, e.g. using `new`. If you make a copy of an object, you don't allocate new memory every time, but rather copy only the pointer to the original block of memory, while incrementing a reference counter that is also stored in memory somewhere such that each copy of the object has access to it. Destroying an object will decrement the reference count and only free the allocated memory if the reference count drops to zero.

A custom copy constructor and assignment operator is all you need for this.

This is basically how shared pointers work.

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as a `cv::Mat` having a shared pointer to a dynamically allocated block of memory. When you copy a `Mat` instance, you copy the shared pointer (incrementing the reference count), not the resource it points to.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `cv::Mat`s can share the same data array but have different header. There is a counter that counts how many mats are using this data array. When the counter reacher 0, the data array is freed. Or it will exist all the time. Besides, `CvMat`、`Mat` and `IplImage` can share the same data array without problem. The only difference between them is header.

Answer (score 1):

> How is it possible to point to the same memory block when it is passed
>   by value?

cv::Mat structure actually manages a dynamically allocated memory location. It just acts a a pointer to this location and carries information on the matrix properties. When you pass this variable by value, you just copy this pointer and dynamic memory is not copied. In order to deep-copy all the elements of a cv::Mat, there is a method called [copyTo()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cv-mat-copyto) .